# How to generate Pusher authentication string from VBscript?

Tags: vbscript, md5, pusher

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339045/how-to-generate-pusher-authentication-string-from-bash) for the same issue in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

Here is my main code:

```
loadFile "md5.vbs"
wscript.echo "md5('test') = " & md5("test")
loadFile "sha256.vbs"
wscript.echo "sha256('test') = " & sha256("test")

method = "POST"
app_id = <redacted>
key = "<redacted>"
secret = "<redacted>"
tstamp = datediff("s",#1970/1/1#,dateadd("h",5,now()))

data = "{""data"":{""message"":""hello world""},""name"":""my_event"",""channel"":""test_channel""}"
path = "/apps/" & app_ID & "/events"
query = "body_md5=" & md5(data) & "&auth_version=1.0&auth_key=" & key & "&auth_timestamp=" & tstamp
sig = sha256(method & vbLf & path & vbLf & query & vbLf & secret)

url = "https://api.pusherapp.com" & path & "?" & query & "&auth_signature=" & sig
wscript.echo url
dim xmlhttp 
set xmlhttp = Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open method,url,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.send data
WScript.echo xmlhttp.responsetext
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

`md5.vbs` can be found [here](https://github.com/Wikinaut/md5.vbs/blob/master/md5.vbs) and `sha256.vbs` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721116/736893).

I get this error:

> Invalid signature: you should have sent HmacSHA256Hex("POST\n/apps/(redacted)/events\nauth_key=(redacted)&auth_timestamp=1471291494&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=(redacted)", your_secret_key), but you sent "(redacted)"

(code edits: Added `secret` to sig, changed `crlf` to `lf`)

Comment: You're using `vbCrLf` (`\r\n`) line breaks, whereas I presume `vbLf` (`\n`-only) line breaks are expected.

Comment: I replaced the 2 instances of `vbCrLf` with `vbLf` and get the same error.

Comment: So what's the exact difference (save for the redacted parts) between the "should" and "is" strings in the error message at this point? Is it just the MD5 value?

Comment: Yes, the "You sent" is a hash.

Comment: I don't understand the `HMacSHA256Hex(param1, your_secret_key)` thing at all.

Comment: The docs say "This should be signed by generating the HMAC SHA256 hex digest with secret key ..." but the vbscript function I have does not accept a parameter for a "key".  Is that my problem?

Comment: That's my guess, yes - I think the idea is to use the key to _encrypt_ the digest, not to have it be part of the data.

Comment: I'm asking innocently: is using VBScript your only option? Can you at least call external utilities?

Comment: It's not my only option, it's just what I have the most experience with.  I'm fairly comfortable with javascript and thus node, but I haven't had luck accessing our SQL database with node.